# how to set different styles to nodes with same classes from one stylesheet in javafx

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have problem in setting styles to my nodes.. I want to have a default style for each node in my scene(.Style2) then I want to set another style for every nodes but the problem is that I have only 1 style sheet and I can't add another because I can not reach the scene in the other classes
here is my stylesheet

```
   .Style1{
    .buttons{
     -fx-background-color: #ccffff;
      -fx-background-radius: 0;


    }

.textfields{
    -fx-background-color: #E4F5F3;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
}
.hboxes{
    -fx-background-color: #ccffff;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
}
}

 .Style2{

.textfields {

    -fx-background-color: #ffffff;
}

.hboxes{
    -fx-border-color: #A2A6A5 ;



}

.buttons{
    -fx-background-color: #1dc7be ;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;


}
 }
```

when I add the style sheet to my scene and add Style2 class  both of these classes will be added to my scene and I don't want this happen...

please help me

thx

Comment: or do we have this syntax in javafx for css? can we write a class into another class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never seen this class hierarchy in a JavaFX CSS file. You can add more than one stylesheet (css file) to the scene or to a node in the scene. If you add a stylesheet to a node it will affect the node and all children and will have a higher priority as the stylesheet of the scene. 
Best practice: You can access the scene from any node (sceneProperty) and then add or remove a second to the scene. This stylesheet will have a higher priority than the first one.